# Strange/weird characters show up in my Python web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in both Python and web scraping.  I used Beautiful Soup 4 and python's html.parser to web scrape a table from a webpage.  The actual HTML table is all text, but some of the cells have large paragraphs of text that may include tabs and returns.

In my output table I get a collection of the following characters in my cells:

1) [u'
2) \r\n
3) ]]
4) I also get a lot of random ' and ] throughout the scraped data.

None of these characters appear in the actual html code itself.

I understand that \r\n are special escape characters for new line and carriage return, but there were none in the actual html script.  I got rid of the tab escape codes (\t) showing up in some of data by using .strip().

I'm wondering whether anyone knows what causes these special characters to appear and more importantly how can I get rid of them?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Cheers.

Edit: Source code:

```
response = requests.get(BASE_URL)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablesorter'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;','')
        dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(text).strip()
        dedented_text = dedented_text.rstrip()
        list_of_cells.append(dedented_text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant scraper code, and ideally produce a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: response = requests.get(BASE_URL)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablesorter'})

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;','')         dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(text).strip() 
        dedented_text = dedented_text.rstrip()
        list_of_cells.append(dedented_text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

Comment: I figured it out it.  Once I encoded everything to 'utf-8' everything worked out.